# Is it possible to have a solution that builds an XBAP and Standard Application as an output?

Tags: wpf, xbap

Is it possible to have a *project* build that produces both a standard version of an application (standard as in just the exe and its required assemblies) and an XBAP version of the application? I have looked on the internet and read my books on WPF and I have not found a way to do this as of yet.

Thanks for your time and I look forward to hearing your answers.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more searching and leafing through the incredibly useful "[Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Presentation-Foundation-Unleashed-WPF/dp/0672328917/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1281359952&sr=1-1)" - I was presented with a link to a site where they supplied a project template to achieve my exact requirement.

For anyone else interested the link is below:

http://scorbs.com/2006/06/04/vs-template-flexible-application/

Thanks!